# Do I get charged every time I create a new AWS WorkSpace?

Tags: amazon-web-services

They say there is always a monthly fee. But does it get charged as the month progresses or right away?

Comment: not a programming question. In fact, why don't you ask amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon WorkSpaces is charged on a pro-rata basis.

So, if you run one for one week and turn it off, you'll be charged approximately one quarter of the monthly fee.

The first month's fee and the last month's fee are similarly pro-rated, based upon how long the WorkSpace was running.

There is no charge for creating a WorkSpace.